# Do file names need to be UTF-8 for solc to be able to compile them?

Tags: solidity, solc

I combed through the [Using the compiler](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.0/using-the-compiler.html) section in the Solidity documentation, but I couldn't find an answer for my question.

Do file names need to be valid UTF-8 for solc to be able to compile them?

Comment: To be precise, Solidity is not a compiler, it's a language. Otherwise no idea.

Comment: To continue the comment above, assuming that your question is therefore about solc, the answer is yes, since it is implemented in C++, and all path names are passed via `std:::string`, as you can see in [the source code](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity).

Comment: Thanks both for the correction. I updated the question body to refer explicitly to "solc".

Comment: Well then, like I said, **this** compiler is implemented in C++, and it uses `std:::string` conclusively. So whatever string format is supported by this type, is also supported by the compiler for file paths and names.

Comment: Your comments make for a perfectly legit answer.

Comment: Note that I've changed the link in my answer to point directly to solc's command-line interface implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solidity Compiler (solc) is implemented in C++ (see [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity)).

It uses `std::string` conclusively, and that includes file names.

Subsequently, whatever string format is supported by this type, is also the string format which you must use when passing file names as [input to the compiler](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/blob/develop/solc/CommandLineInterface.cpp).

Comment: I accepted the answer, but just to clear any doubt: does `std::string` enforce UTF-8? I am not familiar with C++.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg: To my knowledge it supports ASCII, and it happens to allow UTF8 as well.